# Google Maps Error trying to invoke 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get my current location and set a marker on the map with the current location. I put that Toast just to see if the app is retrieving latitude and longitude, and it is, that Toast is working perfectly. The only problem is on the addMarker and the moveCamera, both are showing the same error on logcat.

Can someone please help me? I haven't found any explanation of that error on Google(Not the `NullPointException`, I have found plenty of this one)

Here's the MapsActivty:

```
public GoogleMap mMap;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    String text = "Geo_Location \nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("Marker in currentLocation"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
}
```

And here's the logcat error:

```
03-17 17:26:50.857 13753-13753/com.example.casa.gps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.example.casa.gps, PID: 13753
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your `mMap`?

Comment: Before the onCreate: public GoogleMap mMap

Comment: No, you are declaring it there, not initializing it

Comment: How do you suggest me to initialize? And thanks for the help

Comment: For example doing `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: Thanks man, that really worked out

Comment: Glad to help. I'm posting this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `mMap`:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```